# Get two-factor authentication code from terminal?

Tags: terminal, bash, two-factor-authentication

Is it possible to retrieve my Apple ID two-factor authentication code via the terminal instead of the GUI prompt, i.e. via ssh or a bash script?

I don't own any Apple devices other than a headless Mac mini for iOS development (I am loaning some iOS devices for development, but don't want to mark those as trusted, for obvious reasons).

Right now, I have to remote desktop into the Mac mini to get the 2FA code whenever I need it. I'd like to be able to at least just ssh, if not set up a bash script to text me when prompted.

Comment: Are you looking for Apple's (iCloud) 2FA specifically, or a generic 2FA retrieval mechanism?

Comment: @IconDaemon I'm looking for Apple's 2FA specifically. Updated my post to include that.

Comment: The ultimate hack: take a screenshot and pipe it over SSH.

Answer (score 4):

I came up with a pretty simple solution to this problem using AppleScript that should print the 2FA code:

`#! /usr/bin/env osascript
tell application "System Events"
    if name of every process contains "FollowUpUI" then
        tell window 1 of process "FollowUpUI"
            click button "Allow"
            delay 2
            set code to value of static text 1 of group 1
            log (code)
            click button "Done"
        end tell
    else
        log ("Couldn't find 2FA window")
    end if
end tell
return`

Adding this to a file and making it executable using `chmod +x name_of_file.scpt` should create a script that can be run over ssh by executing `./name_of_file.scpt` while in the same directory as the file.

**Note:** When you run this script over ssh for the first time, the following popup should appear:

[image]

Simply clicking "OK" should allow the script to run properly. This preference will automatically be saved, and can be modified by going into System Preferences->Security & Privacy->Privacy->Accessibility

This worked for me on macOS Mojave, but it may work on other versions as well.